# How to recover data from MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, data-recovery

my MacBook Pro hard drive died (after dropping) I can see the disk when I book from DVD but I don't want to format not to lose data.

What is the best way to recover data? (what hardware and software if any I need)

I have other IMac and Windows computers

Answer (score 4):

Hold down T and power on your Macbook Pro.  This will boot it into target disk mode.  From there, plug it into your iMac via FireWire cable and you'll be able to copy whatever you need off.

Answer (score 2):

If it was mine, I would pull out the drive, mount the drive on the iMac with a USB adapter and  make a dd image before I tried recovering anything. And when I did go to recover files, I'd do it from the dd image and not the physical drive.

After that, I could use OS X disk utils or third party programs to attempt to recovery files without the worry of destroying any data.